# REST web service with Python using WSME

Tags: python, web-services, rest

I'm trying to create a simple REST Web Service using technology WSME reported here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WSME

It's not clear, however, how to proceed. I have successfully installed the package WSME.0.6.4 but I don't understand how to proceed.
On the above link we can see some python code. If I wanted to test the code what should I do? I have to create a .py file? Where this file should be saved? Are there services to be started?
The documentation is not clear: it says "With this published at the / ws path of your application". What application? Do I need to install a Web Server?

Thanks.

Comment: A REST API works on HTTP requests. WSME is a library to expose webservices, not necessarily just REST, on top of an existing web application. It expects that you have a web application, which runs on top of some kind of application server.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a full blown web server to run your application . For example [Apache with mod_wsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) or [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) , but it is not always necessary .

Also you should choose a [web framework](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) to work with .
According WSME doc's it has support for [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) microframework out of the box , which is simple enough to start with .

To get started create a file with the following source code :

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from wsme import WSRoot, expose

class MyService(WSRoot):
    @expose(unicode, unicode)
    def hello(self, who=u'World'):
        return u"Hello {0} !".format(who)

ws = MyService(protocols=['restjson', 'restxml'])
application = ws.wsgiapp()
httpd = make_server('localhost', 8000, application)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Run this file and point your web browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello.xml?who=John`
you should get `<result>Hello John !</result>` in response.

In this example we have used python's [built in webserver](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wsgiref.html) which is a good choice when you need to test something out quickly .

For addition i suggest reading [How python web frameworks and WSGI fit together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219110/how-python-web-frameworks-wsgi-and-cgi-fit-together)