# How to use $.getJSON in JavaScript to retrieve a python file data?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, json, get

How to use $.getJSON in JavaScript to retrieve a python file data?

```
$.getJSON('data.py', function (keyData) {
//code
})
```

data.py

```
import urllib.request, json 
def jsonURL():
    with urllib.request.urlopen("https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/usdeur.json") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    return data
```

Comment: You can’t use getJSON to query the Python file - that needs to be $.get

Comment: Still not getting the JSON data from the python file to show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.ajax` instead to get the Python file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "data.py",
    success: function(response) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

This will query the Python file. However, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158737/get-return-value-from-python-via-javascript-ajax), you need to tell your web server to execute the file instead of returning the contents.